# The module / DOMContentLoaded event conundrum

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, script-tag, domcontentloaded

I used to have a js script which is imported in html as type `text/javascript`. Let's call it `main.js`
I used a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener, so that as the page was loaded, we would run the script.

Now I need more functionality, and I had to create some modules to avoid putting all in a big file.
To import the javascript functions into `main.js`, `main.js` must be imported in html as type module.

However, this makes the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener to never get triggered...

I searched, and in the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event):

> The `DOMContentLoaded` event fires when the HTML document has been completely parsed, and all deferred scripts (`<script defer src="…">` and `<script type="module">`) have downloaded and executed.

This explains, I think, why it never gets triggered inside a type module.

Now, I'm looking for an alternative event... I've tried `load` but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: hum... I think it may be something else. I found some CORS errors in the console, and unlike classic scripts, module scripts require the use of the CORS protocol for cross-origin fetching.

I'll update at a later stage the question.

Comment: It seems that when doing local testing — if you try to load the HTML file locally (i.e. with a file:// URL), you'll run into CORS errors due to JavaScript module security requirements. We need to do the testing through a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, the main problem was exactly what I wrote in my comments.

Module scripts require the use of the CORS protocol for cross-origin fetching.

If one is doing local testing, i.e. loading the HTML file locally (with a uri of the type `file://`), you'll run into CORS errors due to JavaScript module security requirements. We need to do the testing through a server.

In my case, I had to use my Python backend (FastAPI) to serve my webpage, and then it worked, even with the event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Scripts of [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type) `"module"` are [`defer`red](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer) [automatically](https://v8.dev/features/modules#defer), which means they already execute after the DOM was completely loaded. You do not need to do anything yourself to that effect.

So just remove the `DOMContentLoaded` event registration and call the handler immediately.

Comment: Bergi, thanks for the answer. You may be right about the deferred behaviour, however, it was not the main issue.